# "To solution, ..." and also "To this problem, ... " are these even proper phrases?

Tags: phrases, phrase-choice

Consider this phrase:

> "**To solution**, an equation is derived to describe the particle motion."

And also this phrase:

> "**To this problem**, the new proposed method can reduce the weight of the payload significantly."

The questions are: do the phrases in bold texts are *valid* and *common* ?

I have tried to check in Google Scholar, but could not find the result of text with such phrases -- let alone starting in the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are not grammatically correct.

**To solution** doesn't make any sense, because after *to*, we would normally expect a verb, like "*To solve* this problem..." but *solution* is a noun.  Another problem is that *solution* is a [countable noun](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/countable-nouns), so you have to use it with a determiner, like *the solution*, or *a solution*, or *my solution*, but not just *solution* by itself.

**To this problem** isn't much better.  It looks like what you want to say is that an equation is derived or a solution is proposed *regarding* the solution or problem, but we don't say that by beginning "To..." unless a verb is used after it, like

> **To solve this problem**, an equation is derived to describe the particle motion.

or

> **To help with this problem**, the new proposed method can reduce the weight of the payload significantly.